# How to get data after join the 2 collections?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How to write query in **mongoDB** and how to get the value using **meteorJs**.Please suggest me here is the sql query how to convert it into mongoDB.

```
select username, group_id 
from auth_user
join auth_user_groups
       on
     auth_user.id = auth_user_groups.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "join" in mongoDB. If you need to retrieve and mix data from two different collections, you need two queries.

Can you describe what your data model is?

Reading your SQL query, it looks like you have a `user` table (with user details) and a `user_groups` table containing id of groups the user belongs to. Something like:

```
--------------------------
| user_id   | group_id   |
--------------------------
```

Typically this is modeled in mongo by embedding the list of `group_id` inside the `User` object.
Something like:

```
{
    user_id: "",
    name: "John Smith",
    ...
    groups: [
        "group_id_1",
        "group_id_2",
        "group_id_3",
        ]
}
```

So you may have a collection `users` containing `User` objects, with an embedded array `groups` (the same information that - in your relational model - is stored in the separate `user_groups` table), and a separate collection `groups` with `Group` objects containing the details of the groups (name, description, ...)

Comment: Hi alexdown in my app one is auth_user collection having id and username fields and another collection have user_id and group_id.here id in first collection and user_id in second collection are same by using these how to get user name @alexdown

Comment: As said, you are using with mongo the data model you use for a relational database. What's the benefit of having a separate collection? how many groups a user will ever belong to? in the relational world I can understand you want to get your model in 3rd normal form, but here... anyway, if you really really want to keep the collections separate, @Mario 's article offer you some suggestions (point 3 and 4 of the article)

Comment: these are two separate collections and separate functionality by using group_id i want username@ alexdown

Comment: if your problem is "by using group_id I want username" then you should add a "from" clause to your initial SQL query.. ;) anyways, find (https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) supports search inside embedded arrays ($in, https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/selectors), so searching for all users with a given group_id is a query you can do using the denormalized data model I shown you above